# При разработке парсера выводит ошибку: AttributeError: 'ParseVideoCard' object has no attribute 'driver'

Tags: python, aiogram, selenium

[image: Выводит вот такую ошибку, не знаю как исправить, помогите пожалуйста]
Делал парсер вебсайта, но ошибка не позволяет пройти дальше, был бы рад оказанной помощи

```
import logging
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types, utils
from aiogram.types import ParseMode 
from config import TOKEN, URL
from db import process_search_model, init_db , find_id_search, find_all_cards
from parser_1 import ParseVideoCard
logging.basicConfig(level = logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands='list')
async def send_list(message: types.Message):
    search_models = find_id_search(message.chat.id)
    cards = find_all_cards()
    for card in cards:
        card_title = card.title
        for search_model in search_models:
            search_title = search_model.title
            if card_title.find(search_title) >= 0:
                message_text = 'Строка поиска {} \r\n Найдено {}'.format(search_title, utils.markdown.hlink(card_title, card.url))

                await message.answer(text = message_text, parse_mode = ParseMode.HTML)


@dp.message_handler(commands='search')
async def send_search(message: types.Message):
    search_models = find_id_search(message.chat.id)
    for search_model in search_models:
        await message.answer(text = search_model.title)


@dp.message_handler()
async def send_list(message: types.Message):
    await process_search_model(message)


async def scheduled(wait_for, parser):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(wait_for)
        await parser.parse()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    init_db()
    parser = ParseVideoCard(url=URL, bot=bot)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(scheduled(10, parser))
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

```
from aiogram.types import ParseMode
from aiogram import utils
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase('video.db')

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db


class VideoCard(BaseModel):
    title = CharField()
    url = TextField()


class SearchModel(BaseModel):
    title = CharField()
    chatid = CharField()


def find_all_cards():
    return VideoCard.select()


def find_id_search(chat_id):
    return SearchModel.select().where(SearchModel.chatid == chat_id)


def find_all_search():
    return SearchModel.select()


async def process_search_model(message):
    search_exist = True
    try:
        search = SearchModel.select().where(SearchModel.title == message.text).get()
        search.delete_instance()
        await message.answer('Строка поиска {} удалена'.format(message.text))
        return search_exist
    except DoesNotExist as de:
        search_exist = False

    if not search_exist:
        rec = SearchModel(title=message.text, chatid=message.chat.id)
        rec.save()
        await message.answer('Строка поиска {} добавлена'.format(message.text))
    else:
        await message.answer('Строка поиска {} уже есть'.format(message.text))
    return search_exist

async def process_video_card(title, url, chat_id,bot):
    card_exist = True
    try:
        card = VideoCard.select().where(VideoCard.title == title).get()
    except DoesNotExist as de:
        card_exist = False
    
    if not card_exist:
        rec = VideoCard(title=title, url=url)
        rec.save()
        message_text = utils.markdown.hlink(title, url)
        await bot.send_message(chat_id, text=message_text, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
    return card_exist

def init_db():
    db.create_tables([VideoCard, SearchModel])
```

```
from config import DRIVER_PATH, URL
from selenium import webdriver
from db import find_all_search, process_video_card


class ParseVideoCard:
    def __init__(self, url, bot=None):
        if driver is not None:
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_patch = DRIVER_PATH)
        self.driver.minimize_window()
        self.url = url
        self.bot = bot

    def __del__(self):
        self.driver.close()

    async def parse(self):
        search_models = find_all_search()

        for page in range(1, 5):
            print(self.url.format(page))
```

```
URL = "https://www.computeruniverse.net/en/c/hardware-components/pci-express-graphics-cards?page={}"
TOKEN = '6398342628:AAHUte6iPVZmcPIj3A_impBjJ5XmoyiEdNw'
DRIVER_PATH = r'C:Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\chromedriver.exe'[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
```

Comment: Драйвер на гугл хром установлен, версия +- совпадает(на сайте не было точно такой же)

Comment: Логичный вопрос — что такое `driver`?